# Execute a specific action on the first run of the script?

Tags: python, scripting

Id like to execute different action on the first run of the script

for example the first try i want to execute:

```
Print("First Hello")
```

and on the second run.

```
Print("Hello World")
```

i don't understant how to do this, because if i store a variable within the script itself every run the variable will be redefined.

i tried something like this, playing with a new stored variable within blender,

```
    try:
        bpy.context.scene["Auto-Copy Start"] += 1

    except:
        bpy.context.scene["Auto-Copy Start"] = 1
```

and it can totally work. for example

```
try:
    bpy.context.scene["Auto-Copy Start"] += 1
    Print("Hello World")


except:
    bpy.context.scene["Auto-Copy Start"] = 1 #that mean its the first run
    Print("First Hello")
```

But if i save the file and re-run my script it will not work anymore with the saved file, this technique work only for the first run once per file only.

Or i want the first run to execute the first code per blender session. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

**Use the window manager**

Window manager properties only exist for a session, whereas scene properties are stored in the file.

It's good practice to avoid try except clauses. If a custom property `"xxx"` on object `ob` is defined, it will be a member of `ob.keys()` and can be tested for with `"xxx" in ob.keys()`

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
wm = context.window_manager

if "new" in wm.keys():
    print("Not New")
    wm["new"] += 1
else:
    wm["new"] = 1
    print("New")
```

May also be an idea to investigate using a **non** [persistent  on-load handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example). (*Remove the decorator from the example*)